# How to get the attribute from forward - JSP

Tags: jsp, forward, setattribute, getattribute

In `page 1`

```
  <%

  Username user = new Username("username","password","email");
  session.setAttribute("user1", user);

  %>
  <jsp:forward page="Page2.jsp" >
  <jsp:param name="user_1" value="<%= user.getUsername() %>" />         
          </jsp:forward>
```

In `page 2` I want to get the attribute `user_1` from forward. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe ${user.username} ? But we really need to see the code of Username  class.

Comment: That should have been ${user1.username}

Comment: Look I changed the issue

Comment: With your edit, you could try ${param.user_1}

Answer (score 0):

You can access it from request object like below -

```
request.getParameter("user_1")
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the attribute user_1 from forward

You can use implicit object request to retrieve that like this

```
request.getParameter("user_1")
```

or if you want to use EL then

```
${param.user_1}
```